# Is it possible to download files and unzip in the cloud?

Tags: cloud, rar, winrar, winzip

I have a doubt...

I have links to some files (.rar and .zip format) uploaded to Mediafire (I also have others stored in different services) for their respective download.

As additional information, these files are of doubtful origin, and I wouldn't want to infect my PC.

Is there a possibility (apart from installing a virtual machine on my PC) to download those files and have them stored directly in the cloud and not on my PC?

And that these can also be decompressed in the cloud?

In the same way be able to view the multimedia files that those files contain?

Thanks to all.

Comment: No, unless you are running an operating system IN the cloud, they will decompress to your local machine.  Technically, the header of the compressed file can tell you what they contain but I am unsure if either of these utilities will decompress the header without decompressing the rest.  BTW, [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org) is your friend.  It's free, better, and always has been.  Handles rars, zips, and it's own superior format (7z).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So... Once downloaded and stored on the PC... Is there any way to upload the file and decompress these files online and be able to view their content?

Comment: You could upload the decompressed files to "the cloud" (aka someone else's computer).. how to do that would depend on which cloud you speak of.

Comment: How would a VM on your PC relate to said cloud? By cloud, do you mean a VPS? Or some storage like Amazon S3?

Comment: By "the cloud" I mean an OS hosted by Azure, AWS, or any other server farm that puts the processing elsewhere.  "The cloud" also often means other services these companies provide and charge money for but that is not what I am referring to (and I doubt that you are too). A VM on your local PC is really not very different than having it hosted by Microsoft, Amazon, or anyone else.  You are simply communicating with a local IP address rather than a remote one.

Comment: Is there any online service (website) that allows you to enter a download link, and that the downloaded file is stored on that website?

Comment: What's the 'real' problem you're trying to solve? Decompressing locally is a lot more efficient.

Comment: **Updated post information**

Answer (score 0):

If someone shares a compressed ZIP file from a cloud folder, there's no way to unzip it without downloading it to your desktop. From your desktop, you can decompress the file and then work with the contents.